# When do I star a question?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

When do I star and question? Is starring the same as leaving a like? I have seen one other person star one of my questions, and I do not know why.

Note that this is not a duplicate because I am asking when do I star someone else's post? Do I star a post when I like the question? I am not -- for clarification reasons -- asking about how to star a post or what happens when you star a post.

Comment: In light of your latest edit I'd argue that the following sentence from the proposed dupe-target answers your question: _Marking a question as a favorite allows you to easily check back and see when updates are made to the post, and can function as a simple bookmark for questions you might want to reference again in the future._ Basically: star when you think you will want to come back on that question later.

Comment: The dupe explains all sorts of stuff about favorites... except answer this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starring a question is called favoriting it. It's not the same as a like; upvoting is the most similar thing.

Favorite questions will show up in a "favorites" tab in your user profile so you can easily access them:

[image]

The number of favorites will show up as a number below the favorite button on a question. They don't do much except getting enough favorites on a question can earn you the [Favorite Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) and [Stellar Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/stellar-question) badges.

To answer your question, you should favorite questions if they are good and you wish to be able to access them easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can star a question - or "favorite" it - for whatever reason you like but the general intention is that it's a question you want to follow for some reason. While the term "favorite" has the implication that you like the question, that's not even necessary.

I tend to mark questions as favorites when I reference them often. They're questions that are really useful, ones that I link to a lot or need to refer back to because I don't have a perfect memory. Other people favorite questions that need their attention - either they want to write an answer them or they think they're bad questions that they want to follow up on to see if they get handled (closed or improved. Still other people favorite a question that they also have but isn't answered to see if it gets answered.

The connecting factor in these is that they identify **questions you need/want to come back to**. We give you a list of them in your profile for easy reference but we don't give you any notifications when the question is changed - though we do indicate it on your favorites list.

We indicate they've been updated by incrementing the number on the tab in your profile and highlighting the question in yellow:

[image: My favorites list, sorted by "votes" but with yellow highlights on several of the items indicating that they're updated since the last time I viewed the favorites page]

Also, keep in mind that others can see your favorites list while they can't see what you've voted on, so they're definitely not like votes or "likes". The closest analogy to social media would be "following", hence my use of the term in the first paragraph.